# How to define some variables and load a javascript from a source when form is submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

When I submit a form in JSP I want to call a method which defines some variables and then runs a JavaScript file from a source like below and finally submits the form. How can I achieve it? these variables must be defined before the Javascript xyz.js(from source) gets executed. 
Thanks

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  var required_variable1 = 'abcd';
  var required_variable2 = 12;
  var required_variable3 = true;
  var required_variable4 = false; 
</script>  
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://example.com/xyz.js" ></script>
```

UPDATE: 
I know about the onsubmit(). I tried to do like this but its complaining about inserting this script inside the script. What is the correct syntax/way to do it?

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://example.com/xyz.js"/>
```

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  $('#acceptanceForm').submit(function() {
    var required_variable1 = 'abcd';
    var required_variable2 = 12;
    var required_variable3 = true;
    var required_variable4 = false;
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://example.com/xyz.js"/>
  }); 
</script>
```

Comment: read about the onsubmit event

Comment: @madalinivascu Thanks...I know about onsubmit() but I'm not sure how to include that external javaScript.. I tried as above but I know its syntactically wrong. giving syntax error... Can you please suggest the correct way to load the external javascript from src="https://example.com/xyz.js"  inside that submit function?

Comment: why are you appending a script tag inside a script tag?

Comment: @madalinivascu I want to load that external JavaScript (https://example.com/xyz.js) after those variables have defined. I know that appending is wrong but want to know how to load that Js inside the function.

Comment: then place the script tag after the first script tag

Comment: @madalinivascu If I place it after the Script tag, its not loading that javascript when I click the submit button. maybe it is loading even before clicking the submit.

Comment: what code do you have in xyz.js?you need to wrap that code in a function and call it in your submit event

Comment: right now your code is executing when the page is loaded

Comment: xyz.js is some external source. if I define some of the pre defined variables like var required_variable1 = 'abcd';
in my script before calling that external JS, it will return me a an encoded string which will be stored in the hidden field <input type="hidden" name="abcd" id="abcd">. So this process of defining those variables (required_variable1) should happen before calling/loading that external JS. And also this whole process should be triggered when click the form submit button..

Comment: @madalinivascu and I can not wrap that whole code from the external source it should only be loaded from a URL only.

Comment: without seeing you xyz.js code i can't help you, why do you need to call this script on submit?

Comment: @madalinivascu it is actually https://mpsnare.iesnare.com/snare.js. which gets me a encoded string with some blackbox String. we can access the url and see.. It will collect the Users IP address in some encoded string

Comment: from the documentation my reasoning for putting the script tag after the first script tag is correct see:https://developer.bazaarvoice.com/conversations-api/tutorials/submission/device-fingerprinting/iovation-web

Comment: @madalinivascu thanks for this...I checked it. so it only can be loaded whenever the page is loaded, but not possible to load with the submit event. right?

Comment: you can't load a file in a event, you need to load them when the page is loaded and then call them